# Get line in content editable HTML box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `contenteditable=true` divider in HTML.

I'd like to get the line that the caret is on.

I have tried the jQuery caret plugin. It did not work.

I use the function below to get the caret position on the current line:

I use the library `https://github.com/timdown/rangy`.

```
rangy.init();
function getFirstRange() {
   var sel = rangy.getSelection();
   return sel.rangeCount ? sel.getRangeAt(0) : null;
}
```

The HTML is `<div contenteditable="true></div>`

How do I get the line that the caret is on?

**Updated Below**

[This is a text area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr8yZ.png):

- The line with the 1s on it is line 0
- The line with the 2s on it is line 1
- The line with the 3s on it is line 2
- The line with the 4s on it is line 3

The cursor is on line 3 (the one with the 4s on it). We know this from looking at it (at the very end of line 3).

**How can we find out which line the cursor is on, in a `<textarea></textarea>` or `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`?**

In the example image, the cursor is on line 3.

I need this because the element's content is updated via a network and I want to update the cursor position to what it was before automatically updating the content, which is how http://PiratePad.net works.

Comment: Add html example to better understanding.

Comment: The visible line created by automatic text wrapping, or the line defined by elements inside the content editable?

Comment: are you using a button to trigger this function?

Comment: @Teemu ah, it's the line defined by the elements

Comment: @JoëlBonetRodríguez yes, it's on a keyup or mouseup event!

Comment: are you using this to perform an ajax search or you only want to get the value of the box?

in the first case, use a submit button and capture with standard ajax functions, If it's the second case try to use $('#box_id').val() to get the value on keypress.

Comment: @JoëlBonetRodríguez nah, I'd like to get the cursor index and what line its on. I've already got the index but not the line.

Comment: sorry but, you must edit the original answer in order to make us understand exactly what you want, what you need and why you want that.

Comment: @JoëlBonetRodríguez I have added details, an example and a working example (closed source) :)

Comment: I recommend you to use textarea for this job, then get the val() with jquery on key press function. Then split for new line. You'll get an array with N positions. In that case you'll get array[0][1][2][3]. So you can loop the array in Y positions. Last one will be the current cursor line. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @JoëlBonetRodríguez thanks but I need the contenteditable div to be there, since I'm using HTML tags like <i> and <b> in it :p

Comment: I never did it with a div but must be a way, more or less as with you can do using textarea...